# base_url() getting error in code igniter 1.7.3

Tags: codeigniter

Install Code ignitor 1.7.3 and try to convert my existing project which is in 1.7.1  but getting **Call to undefined function base_url()**

Comment: Have you included the URL library in your autoload file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably replaced your autoload.php with the default one in config.php, so now you are not automatically loading url_helper.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set the the variable in the config/config.php
$config['base_url']